# Make two DIVs the same height? #2

Tags: javascript, html, css, height

I made this topic earlier and a solution has been suggested, but for some reason it doesn't work and I hope to find some further help.

I want to make two DIVs the same height (so when one div becomes bigger in height, the other one should do the same).

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="aProductHeader">
    <div class="omschrijving">
        <h3>omschrijving</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="aProduct">
    <div class="omschrijving">
        <span class="entry inner">
            Toddler bestek blauw
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like `.aProductHeader .omschrijving` and `.aProduct .omschrijving` to keep the same height.

This is my current CSS:

```
.aProductHeader .omschrijving {
    background: #cac;
    min-height: 30px;
}

.aProduct .omschrijving {
    background: #cec;
    min-height: 30px;
}
```

And this is the solution which has been suggested to me, I put this before the :

```
<script>

var one = document.getElementsByClassName(".aProductHeader .omschrijving"),
    two = document.getElementsByClassName(".aProduct .omschrijving");

for (i = 0; i < one.length; i++)
{
  if (one[i].offsetHeight > two[i].offsetHeight)
  {
    two[i].style.height = one[i].offsetHeight+"px";
  }else{
    one[i].style.height = two[i].offsetHeight+"px";
  }
}

</script>
```

However, the result I am still getting is this:

[image: unequal height]

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: why don't you put both in one class? and make them both relative and height 100%?

Comment: You can do this using `CSS` only. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/868WD/) - Try using `display: table;`

Comment: Tried both of these solutions but they both do nothing when I apply them. :s

Comment: @2339870 Well by my demo you can see that it works. Provide more relevant code and I will have a look. Make a JSFiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QAEy4/

Comment: Could the fact that I'm using media queries have something to do with the code not working in my full page?

Comment: @2339870 Like this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/QAEy4/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Is [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/nL2B3/) what you are trying to do?

I tried using `display:table` & `display: table-cell;`.

**CSS**

```
#kasticketProducts{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:250px; /* for testing only */
    display: table;
}
.aProductHeader{
    display: table-cell; 
    background: #cac;
}

.aProduct{
    background: #cec;
    display: table-cell;     
}
```

Check this [blog](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-equal-height/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...
Actually header  has margin so write CSS for h3 as

```
h3 {
margin: 0;
}
```

If above is working then try below structure..

```
<div>
<div class="aProductHeader">
    <div class="omschrijving">
        <h3>omschrijving</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="aProduct">
    <div class="omschrijving">
        <span class="entry inner">
            Toddler bestek blauw
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and add this CSS to your CSS

```
.aProductHeader .omschrijving {
    background: #cac;
    min-height: 30px;
}
.aProductHeader {
    float: left;
}
.aProduct {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.aProduct .omschrijving {
    background: #cec;
    min-height: 30px;
}
h3 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

working example
http://jsfiddle.net/e6ba3/

Answer (score 0):

```
.aProduct{background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-left: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
border-right: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
position: relative;} .aProductHeader{border-top: 1px solid #CA542B;
float: left;
min-height: 65px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
padding-top: 4px;
position: relative;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
width: 70px;
z-index: 2;}.wrap{border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
padding-right: 1px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 70px;
z-index: 1;} 

Wtrite your html
  <div class="wrapper" style="position:realtive;border:1px solid red;"> 
    <div class="wrap"></div>
    <div calss="aProductHeader">xxxxx</div><div class="aProduct">xxx</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

No need to write Javascript/jQuery, you can achieve this through CSS.

It will be flexible, and keep both div height same.

Here is Code:

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="aProductHeader">
        <div class="omschrijving">
            <h3>omschrijving</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="aProduct">
        <div class="omschrijving">
            <span class="entry inner">
                Toddler bestek blauw
            </span>
            <span class="entry inner">
                Toddler bestek blauw
            </span>
            <span class="entry inner">
                Toddler bestek blauw
            </span>
            <span class="entry inner">
                Toddler bestek blauw
            </span>
            <span class="entry inner">
                Toddler bestek blauw
            </span>
            <span class="entry inner">
                Toddler bestek blauw
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main { position:relative; display:table;}
.aProductHeader .omschrijving {
    background: #cac;
    min-height: 30px;
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    position:absolute; left:0; top:0; bottom:0;
}

.aProduct .omschrijving {
    background: #cec;
    min-height: 30px;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    margin-left:160px;
}
```

Enjoy !!!

Comment: What the hell is this?

Comment: It looks like you just threw loads of random `CSS` together until it worked. (I don't know if this will work as I haven't tried it, maybe make a demo). But I can tell that you have no idea what you was doing. `position: absolute`, `float: left;` and `margin-left: 160px;` That makes no sense, please do not submit answers if you have no idea what your doing.

Comment: See this Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/M8Kjz/), I have implemented this technique in one my project.

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/M8Kjz/)

Comment: What fiddle? And it doesn't matter if you used it. Its a bad solution and half the `CSS` doesn't need to be there. Just looked at it, yeah don't use this. No need for the absolute positioning.

Comment: Please look at this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/868WD/) - this is a better solution. There are other ways but I would not recommend using yours.

Comment: Ooopps, Aplogies,
Thanks for sharing. 
I will take care of it next time.